# Evaluate the line integral using two methods : directly and green

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Consider the line integral

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYll.png)
[bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whYeG.png)

i get how to find the parametize equations. 
what i dont get is how they find the upper and lower bounds for the integrals.

so for c1= y=0 ; x =t ; 0
c3 x=1-t; y=2-2t; 0

the upper and lower bound limits for integration?

Comment: Hi bc5803, welcome to MSE! I'm afraid the images you uploaded are far too small to see, could you please upload larger images?

Comment: hi. i resubmitted it just now.  sorrry

Comment: They haven't yet, in the images you have submitted. Could you please show Step 3 of 7?

Comment: i dont really need to know steps 3 to 7. i just need to know how you get the upper and lower bounds for integrations. thats all.

Comment: Instead of posting images of critical parts of your questions, take the time to enter that information as text. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. MathJax is used here for formatting mathematical expressions. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).